# SSL installation help cPanel

Tags: ssl, paypal, cpanel

I recently purchased a SSL certificate from my domain registrar (http://www.namecheap.com), and I'm trying to install it on my website in cPanel. The certificate I bought was PositiveSSL.  I filled out a form on namecheap, and got an email with a thing that says -----Begin Certificate------ AbunchOfLetters -----End certificate ----

So in cPanel, I generated a private key. Then I went to "Manage SSL sites" in cPanel. I pasted in the certificate emailed to me in the first field, then put my generated private key in the second field. When I put the private key in, it says it doesn't match the certificate and I'm not able to install it.

I've been scratching my head at this for a while. Sorry if I missed something, I'm not very familiar with how SSL works, but would really appreciate some help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add your private key which you have got while creating the CSR for the SSL, if you are not sure about that, Please contact your hosting provider for this. They will check it on the server and will install SSL on your domain with the correct private key.